# If two subsequences converge to different values, prove directly the sequence itself diverges

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> Let $\{x_n\}$ be a sequence. Suppose that there are two convergent subsequences 
>   $\{x_{n_{\Large{i}}} \}$ and $\{x_{m_{\Large{i}}} \}$. 
>   Suppose that
>   $\lim\limits_{i\to\infty} x_{n_{\Large{i}}} = a$    and 
>   $\lim\limits_{i\to\infty} x_{m_{\Large{i}}} = b$,
>   where $a \ne b$. Prove that $\{x_n\}$ is not convergent.

I have to prove this without using the idea that subsequences are convergent if the sequence is convergent and their limits are equal. I have no idea where to go with this problem and have been stuck on it for quite some time now.

Answer (score 4):

Let $\epsilon=\dfrac{|b-a|}3,$ and note that $\epsilon>0$.

Now, show that for all $N,$ there exist $m,n\ge N$ such that $|x_n-x_m|\ge\epsilon$. Thus, the sequence is not Cauchy, and so not convergent. **Hint**: If $|x_{n_i}-a|\le\epsilon$ and $|x_{m_i}-b|\le\epsilon,$ what can we say about $|x_{n_i}-x_{m_i}|$ in light of the fact that $|b-a|=3\epsilon$?

Comment: This seems to be where I keep getting stuck. I get confused on how to show that such an m and n exist.

Comment: I have rephrased my post slightly to make the hint a bit clearer. Does that help?

Comment: yes it does, thank you.

Comment: although, how do I create the relationship between the two inequalities?

Comment: I recommend that you apply the triangle inequality to $|b-a|,$ after rewriting "$b-a$" in an equivalent way. Think on it for a bit, and let me know if you're still stuck.