# If the sequence $\left\{a_n\right\}$ has no two subsequence converging to two different limits then the sequence has a limit?

Tags: convergence-divergence

If the sequence $\left\{a_n\right\}$ has no two subsequence converging to two different limits then the sequence has a limit?

Can I understand the question in the way that: If all the convergent subsequences of  $\left\{a_n\right\}$  converge to the same limit, then the sequence has a limit? 
Does this question has a counter example?

Comment: It could be that the sequence has no convergent subsequence (e.g., $a_n=n$), in which case the "if" statement holds vacuously, but the "then" statement is false.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [If two subsequences converge to different values, prove directly the sequence itself diverges](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/433245/if-two-subsequences-converge-to-different-values-prove-directly-the-sequence-it)

Comment: I think if you take any 2 convergent subsequences of \left\{a_n\right\}, they have to have the same limit. But I dont know how to prove the sequence has the limit.

Comment: @GAVD Not the same question. More care, please.

Answer (score 0):

As stated, the question has some trivial counter-examples, as angryavian mentioned, since $(a_n)$ may not have any convergent subsequences. In that case the condition "$\{a_n\}$ has no two subsequences that converge to two different limits" is satisfied trivially; so are conditions of the form "if all the convergent subsequences...". The sequence $a_n := n$ then gives a trivial counter-example.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $\overline{\lim} a_n$ and $\underline{\lim} a_n$ are always two particular subsequences of $(a_n)_n$.

If $a_n$ is bounded, these are monotonic sequences in a compact thus always converge.

So if you require that no two subsequences converge to different values, then it is also true for these two, and $\underline{\lim}=\overline{\lim}$ means $a_n$ converge.

Now if $a_n$ is not bounded, as stated there may not be converging subsequences [e.g. $a_n=n$].

Yet if you consider compactified $\mathbb R\cup\{-\infty,+\infty\}$ then the extended condition still impose $\underline{\lim}=\overline{\lim}$ so $a_n$ diverges to $\pm\infty$. This is a result stronger than just unbounded.